# How to clean untracked files from uninitialised submodule

Tags: git

Suppose you clone a repo that has submodules, but not recursively:

```
git clone ...foo.git
cd foo
```

And then some untracked files are added to the submodule directory (before it is initialised/updated):

```
echo "Hello" > asubmodule/pesky_file.txt
```

How do you remove such files? As far as I can tell there's no combination of `git` commands that can do it.

- `git clean -ffxd` just ignores the file, even if you `cd asubmodule` first.
- `git submodule update --init` fails because the `asubmodule` directory is not empty.
- `git submodule foreach` ignores it because the submodule has not been updated.

Is there any way to do this except `rm -rf asubmodule/*`?